# How websites know (e.g. facebook ) my selenium webdriver App have deployed on cloud (e.g. Heroku) or Desktop?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

My simple test App is create an Account in Facebook.

It works fine in my desktop, but when I deploy it on cloud I get this message

[image]

I have tried to make this works 
so I want to know what is the difference that make facebook know and what  can do to make it works?

I use node.js and selenium webdriver And Phantomjs.

Comment: Probably just IP ranges blacklisting.

Comment: Yeah, Heroku is AWS and they publish their IP ranges.

Comment: so what can i  do ? .. what do you suggest ?